# How to count user records in subdocument in express

Tags: express, mongoose

I have a index route for users. I need to count the records they have in the subdocument. This is my index route:

```
router.get('/', middleware.isLoggedIn, (req, res, next) => {
  // get all users from db
  User
    .find({})
    .populate('gifts')
    .exec(function (err, allUsers) {
      if (err) {
        req.flash('error', err.message);
      }

      res.render('users/index', {
        users: allUsers,
        title: 'Users',
        breadcrumbsName: 'Users'
      });
    });
});
```

I'm using .populate as it's my understanding it's like a inner join. So in my ejs I want to do something like Total Gifts, and the sum of all giftAmount. This is my giftSchema

```
const schema = new Schema({
  user: {
    type: Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
    required: true,
    index: true
  },
  ..
  giftAmount: Types.Number,
  ..
});
```

Am I doing this correctly? What am I missing?

UPDATE. I am updating the document to have my user schema per request.

```
const
  mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  Schema = mongoose.Schema,
  Types = Schema.Types,
  passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');

const paymentPreference = {
    paypalEmail:Types.String,
    check: {
      addressLine1: Types.String,
      addressLine2: Types.String,
      city: Types.String,
      state: Types.String,
      zipCode: Types.String
    }
};

let UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  firstName: Types.String,
  lastName: Types.String,
  aliasFirstName: Types.String,
  aliasLastName: Types.String,
  username: Types.String,
  phone: Types.String,
  password: Types.String,
  isAdmin: Types.Boolean,
  addressLine1: Types.String,
  addressLine2: Types.String,
  city: Types.String,
  state: Types.String,
  zipCode: Types.Number,
  profilePic: {
    type: Types.String,
    default: 'https://s.gravatar.com/avatar/0a07df079fd7a07e4cd0e5668835296c?s=80'
  },
  preferredPaymentMethod: {
    type: Types.String,
    enum: ['', 'paypal', 'check', 'deposit'],
    default: ''
  },
  paymentPreference: {
    type: paymentPreference
  },
  lastLoginDate: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

Comment: Can you post your UserSchema as well?

Comment: @iagowp i've updated the post with my full UserSchema

Comment: Ok, what is the exact data you want? You want to get all users, then what? The method populate fills the fields. For example, if your user schema had a field called gifts, with all the gifts he ever gave/received in an array, and you loaded this user, the array would contain only the gifts ids, but not their data, like giftAmount, name of the gift, etc, so when you do user.find().populate('gifts'), now this search will return the user with an array containing a copy of the gift document

Comment: So I need to access all the gift data belonging to the user on this index route.

Comment: In that case, look for the gift where the user is the one you want, and if you need the user data as well, populate the user.

Comment: `aggregate` is the "inner join", and you can `$sum` fields. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/

Comment: @QiaosenHuang how do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I'm able to do is what's called a virtual type and use the getter to return it in my model!

```
UserSchema.virtual('giftCount').get(function () {
  return this.gifts.length;
});
```